# Matplotlib: emoji font does not work when using backend_pdf

Tags: pdf, matplotlib, fonts, emoji, axis-labels

I want to use the emoji-font "Symbola.ttf" to label my plots. This does work when I use `plt.show()`. But it does not work when using the backend_pdf. Only two emojis are shown in a mixed up order.

#### example images:

when using `plt.show()`:

[image: when using <code>plt.show()</code>]

when using the backend_pdf:

[image: when using the backend_pdf]

#### example code:

Here is my code to produce these examples:

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import emoji
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

emojis = [emoji.EMOJI_UNICODE[e] for e in list(emoji.EMOJI_UNICODE.keys())[620:630]]
prop = FontProperties(fname='./Symbola.ttf', size=30)

# backend_pdf plot
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("output.pdf")
plt.xticks(range(len(emojis)), emojis, fontproperties=prop)
pdf.savefig()
pdf.close()

# plt.show() plot
plt.xticks(range(len(emojis)), emojis, fontproperties=prop)
plt.show()
```

I'm running this on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem. It seems that my Symbola.ttf was broken. When I use this [.ttf file](https://github.com/stv0g/unicode-emoji/blob/master/symbola/Symbola.ttf) everything works great.